# sudo cat /dev or /proc

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to get data output from certain directories such as `/proc` and `/dev`. I can get most data from `/proc`. However nothing from `/dev`. I understand that its main output is devices connected to the computer.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSq5Q.png) - See image for details of the task.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Hello, this is your data horde program. Please continue."
sleep 5s
#
#
# This is a auto download and install applications
echo "Installing software for scan."
yes Y | apt-get install cat
yes Y | apt-get install nmap
sleep 5s
echo "Installation complete."
#
#
# This area of the script will scan for IP information and output to certain 
text files.
echo "Scanning for IP address."
ifconfig &>> bashscanip.txt
sudo ss -tulwn &>> bashscanip.txt
sudo top -b -n 5  &>> processme.txt
sleep 5s
echo "Scan complete, scanning computer data."
#
# Cat export data into easy read text file hardware scan from /proc & /dev
sudo cat /proc/*  &>> bashdevinfo.txt
sudo cat /dev/*  &>> bashdevinfo.txt
set -e
sleep 5s
echo "Scan complete, please continue to check files."
sleep 5s
echo "Exiting Program"
sleep 5s
kill $$
#
# References
# https://stackabuse.com/how-to-permanently-set-path-in-linux/
# https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shell_Comments
# https://vitux.com/find-devices-connected-to-your-network-with-nmap/
# https://www.tecmint.com/save-top-command-output-to-a-file/
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130829/how-to-self-terminate-a- 
bash-script-after-timeout
```

Thanks

Comment: My objective is to gain information and output it to a file. Such as the /proc commands. It's just that I cannot gain any information from /DEV.

Comment: What "information"? There are no "/proc *commands*", what do you mean? Please tell us what you are trying to do because using `cat` on these things doesn't make sense. For one thing, `cat` on the files in `dev` will make a direct copy of all of the contents of all of your hard drives. You can't possibly save that to a new file since it will be the size of your hard drive! Do you just want `ls` instead, perhaps?

Comment: Check the image. I was given a task to gain information based on my computer system. I can't really explain it other than just copying the image. Thanks for advance, I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to Linux.

Comment: We are not solving school tasks. I can give a hint that you need `ls` instead of `cat`.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](//askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with this script and what do you want to know from the title or this question, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `cat`. `cat` is simply a program that copies what you give it as input and prints it out. So, if you do something like `cat /dev/sda1 > file`, then `file` will be an [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) of the first partition of your hard drive. That will be the same size as your partition, so can't even be saved onto the partition. It is also useless information, it won't be text, it just doesn't make sense here.

You can use `ls` to list the contents of the directory:

```
ls /proc >> bashdevinfo.txt
ls /dev >> bashdevinfo.txt
```

But this isn't what you are supposed to do either. You are supposed to collect information from the relevant files. So read up on what `/proc` is and how it works and see how you can extract useful information from the files in it. Some hints:

- See the files `/proc/meminfo`, `/proc/mounts` and `/proc/uptime` for starters.
- Figure out what you want to show and *then* think about how you can show it. Don't just blindly look at everything.

Comment: A good answer!!

Comment: @terdon, cheers I'll give it a try. Sorry about being a newbie on here :) don't mean any harm. I'll give the formatting tools an overlook.